# Android payment processing through paypal/credit card

Tags: android, paypal, payment, credit-card

How to process the payment by paypal/credit card from a android app? Right now I have been converting an online website into an android app. And the final process is processing paypal/credit card payment. I don't know how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue with Paypal then this link will help you

read (1,2,3 article) & download pay[pal API from it
https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-2991 
This api also have source code with it.

Comment: thanks buddy. i have done it with the help [link](https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-2532) and the thing is that both the links asks for the submittion of the app inorder to get the app id which is much when changing the mode to live.. Have u seen any thing that dont need this thing...

Comment: then what's the problem with that

Comment: when i posted this i dont have any idea of going abt that. After find this one it worked fine, but the problem is i need to get the api key for running it in live mode. so searching for any possibility of doing it without that key...

Comment: But i had also implement it but it did'nt require any API key

Comment: @Amandeepsingh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1796/discussion-between-dinash-and-amandeep-singh)

Comment: in live mode  ? what u want to know

Comment: what i want is whether the process works perfectly in live mode without the api key...

Comment: yes it works on my emmulator i had create  a dublicate account in paypal ans do one transection with that & also ui receive the message fron paypal regarding the transection of my account.

Comment: do you want to joinin the chat room.My chat room name is(Learn Android).

Comment: Link is broken, oyu can use this one: http://web.archive.org/web/20110323064137/https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-2991

Answer (score 1):

You should consider in-app billing. I'm not sure what your business model is but this is probably the best way to charge from within your app.

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

Comment: IAB is only supported on devices where Google Play is installed. Many devices on the market, especially outside the US and Western Europe do NOT have Google Play installed, meaning that you end up losing revenue. Go with PayPal. You post was back in 2011 and this is 2013 and Google still hasn't provided proper support for the international community.