# Does Paypal process credit/debit cards in Android applications without logging into a paypal account and how?

Tags: android, paypal

Ok, I called paypal today and asked them if they can take debit/credit cards through a mobile application. They said no. However, online people write it like there is a way.

Also, I emailed a mobile company pretending I didn't feel secure about giving them my card info and asked them how they were taking credit/debit cards through their application and they responded that they used Paypal for that!

So I am confused. Anyone here has taken a credit/debit card payment in android without logging in to Paypal?

I searched everywhere including here in stackoverflow:

[Android payment processing through paypal/credit card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428943/android-payment-processing-through-paypal-credit-card)

But I am still uncertain. Can anyone have a definite answer and not just send me to some some other link.

Update: It seems this can be done, does anyone have a tutorial on how to do this?

UPDATE 2: I gave up with paypal trying to do this. I now use zooz. I highly suggest anyone going into the trouble of getting paypal working for them to use zooz. Its soo easy. Btw, I don't work for zooz, I use them for my apps. Their website is zooz.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to take PayPal payments through your mobile device, and it's not all that difficult either. Just use PayPal payments and embed their payment gateway (webpage) into a WebView. You can optionally receive feedback through IPN, and fire off a GCM event to your app.

No, you will not be able to take the customer's credit card number and other information, feed it to PayPal and process the payment. But the point of using PayPal is that all the security of capturing, transferring and storing that info (including the significant liability that comes with handling it securely!) is PayPal's responsibility, not yours.

Keep in mind that you would violate the Google Play/Market TOS if you're using PayPal to charge for your app or digital content within the app. If you're creating a shopping app, however, you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks. Is funny because I asked the PayPal guys the exact same question and they told me it was impossible to use a web view. They said their APIs would know is coming from mobile device and it wouldn't accept it. I should have known Better and followed my instincts. I guess I will be spending my weekend on this. BTW, I am selling physical stuff on my app, so it won't violate Google terms, that's the first thing I checked. Thank you. So do you have any example? Haha

Comment: I updated my answer. I am using zooz now in my application. Paypal needs to update their stuff to be easier to integrate into apps.